# Change Wordpress menu names in child them

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

My parent theme (html5blank) has 3 menus set up my default in it's functions.php. I want to amend their names in my child theme so they make more sense for my client.

I've tried copying the code into my child theme functions.php and renaming the `register_html5_menu` function but it won't work as there's no reference to the menus in the templates - presumably because this function is related to the CMS?

Here's the code from the parent theme:

```
function register_html5_menu()
{
    register_nav_menus(array( // Using array to specify more menus if needed
        'header-menu' => __('Header Menu', 'html5blank'), // Main Navigation
        'sidebar-menu' => __('Sidebar Menu', 'html5blank'), // Sidebar Navigation
        'extra-menu' => __('Extra Menu', 'html5blank') // Extra Navigation if needed (duplicate as many as you need!)
    ));
}
```

Can anyone think of away to amend the names/possibly add new menus via the child theme functions.php?

Also, what is the second 'html5blank' name for? "Header Menu" is the only thing that shows up in the CMS and I see these 'second comments' throughout the functions file. Just wondering what they do, if anything?

Answer (score 0):

The `register_html5_menu()` function needs to be called the snippet you provide only defines the function.

Can you try adding

```
add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_html5_menu' );
```

to your functions.php file after the function.

On you question about the second 'html5blank' I think is more a question about the translation text function `__()`

More info here:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/__/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried adding the code you provided after the function in my original post but nothing changes. I tried adding a priority like this `add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_html5_menu', 100 );` but still nothing. I guess the original function in the parent functions.php is still taking priority?

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'register_my_menu' );

function register_my_menu() {
    register_nav_menu( 'header-menu', __( 'Header Menu' ) );
    register_nav_menu( 'sidebar-menu', __( 'Sidebar Menu' ) );
    register_nav_menu( 'extra-menu', __( 'Extra Menu' ) );
}
```